# Why frequent switching hidden property of CALayer causes extreme graphics degradation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I am writing **IOS** app where many **CALayers** (hundreds) are displayed at the same time on screen. Update of interface (at rate about **50-60Hz**) includes removing/adding some **CALayers** from/to layers hierarchy and changing "hidden" state of other **CALayers**. All updates are made under common **CATransaction** with **ANY** animations swithed off.

Frequent removing/adding **CALayers** from hierarchy doesn't lead to any problems with graphics performance. But frequent changing of "hidden" state of **CALayers** leads to degradation of FPS so graphics updates stop being smooth and stable. It seems that **GPU** always late with processing updated screen.

Does anyone know what is the reason for this effect? In official documentation there is no any word about such side effects of hiding/showing layers. Adding/removing and hiding/showing layers seem to have similar consequences to what is made with layers: when layer is hidden it is just not processed at all what is equivalent to being removed (except maybe that it is still cached somewhere in GPU..?). Maybe someone can explain that or faced the same problem?

Comment: How about changing alpha? It seems that GPU rendering are waiting for something if missed one cycles. Add layer and remove layer are happening in CPU side. So the final should have no problem. That’s what I am reasonable guessing

Comment: Need to try change alpha..
Any ideas why cycles are missed? The fact is that while some layers are hidden others are not and being updated every time.
About CPU load for adding/removing CALayers: yes it is really huge, noticed that. But now it is the only way now to have good graphics performance.

Comment: I think I found the reason. Animatable is also for the hidden. So there is 0.25 second  intrinsic animation duration. You may use CATransaction() to change the duration to 0.0 and then change it in begin() and end() block. Remember, CALayer is an animation layer and not static as CGLayers.

Comment: I written that I use CATransaction with disabled animation.. It is not that issue, unfortunately..

Comment: Did you call flush() somehow? You can also group CATransaction() to make them change altogether if there are many layers changing

Comment: No, I have never used flush().. Is it worth to try? In documentation said that it is unnecessary for main thread (cause it has run loop). I use main thread to update views. As for CATransaction() so I use it to update all my layers.

Comment: Depends on the number of layers. Use it may help

Comment: Tried changing ALPHA instead of HIDDEN. Seems to be better but still degrades. May be it is because of TOO many layers involved..

Comment: Another issue is why updating of ONLY ONE layer causes increase of CPU load by 60-70% (not APP itself, but other processes load)???

Comment: Maybe that’s the real layer need to prepare. Others will be shallow handling. Without code, it’s hard to reveal. Maybe you can trace to the code from profile

Comment: It is difficult to insert all code here cause it is spread around multiple classes. But I tried to describe it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54590531/why-updating-calayer-causes-to-increase-of-cpu-usage-by-other-processes-by-60