# Why updating CALayer causes increase of CPU usage (by other processes) by 60-70%?

Tags: ios, performance, core-animation, calayer, cpu-usage

I am witing **IOS** app when interface is presented by many **CALayers**. Once I noticed that **CPU** is loaded by other processes (not app actually) during graphics updates. I began to disabled updating of interface parts and went to the moment when only ONE **CALayer** was updated (at **50-60 Hz**), but all other layers (hundreds) were statically displayed too. So updating of only this ONE layer costs **60-70% of CPU** load by other processes. When disable update of this only layer, **CPU** is not loaded.

Can anyone say what is going on here??

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

// update layer which is sublayer of self.view.layer
self.headingCircularScaleLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(DegToRad(-newHeadingAngle_deg), 0, 0, 1);

[self.view.layer setNeedsLayout];

[CATransaction commit];
```

Here **headingCircularScaleLayer** is CALayer which contents is set to some Image

**NOTE_1:** (test of CPU load by adding many layers  and updating them)

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self createAndSetupLayers];

    CADisplayLink *displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateLayers)];
    [displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    self.startTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(void) createAndSetupLayers {

    NSMutableArray<CALayer*>* newLayersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    long numOfRows = 28;
    long numOfCols = 21;
    long numOfLayers = numOfRows * numOfCols;

    CGFloat cellWidth = self.view.bounds.size.width / numOfCols;
    CGFloat cellHeight = self.view.bounds.size.height / numOfRows;

    CGFloat layerWidth = cellWidth * 0.9;
    CGFloat layerHeight = cellHeight * 0.9;

    long currRow = 0;
    long currCol = 0;

    for (long i = 0; i < numOfLayers; i++)
    {
        currRow = i / numOfCols;
        currCol = i % numOfCols;

        CALayer* newLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];

        newLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, layerWidth, layerHeight);
        newLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        newLayer.position = CGPointMake((currCol + 0.5) * cellWidth, (currRow + 0.5) * cellHeight);
        newLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
        //newLayer.opacity = 0.5;

        //NSDictionary *newActions = @{ @"transform": [NSNull null] };
        //newLayer.actions = newActions;
        newLayer.actions = @{ @"contents": [NSNull null], @"position": [NSNull null],
                           @"frame": [NSNull null], @"opacity": [NSNull null],
                           @"bounds": [NSNull null], @"affineTransform": [NSNull null],
                           @"sublayerTransform": [NSNull null], @"transform": [NSNull null],
                           @"zPosition": [NSNull null], @"anchorPoint": [NSNull null],
                           @"cornerRadius": [NSNull null], @"sublayers": [NSNull null],
                           @"onLayout": [NSNull null], };


        CALayer* newColorLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
        newColorLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, layerWidth, layerHeight);
        newColorLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
        newColorLayer.position = CGPointMake(0.5 * layerWidth, 0.5 * layerHeight);
        newColorLayer.opacity = 0.5;
        newColorLayer.opaque = YES;
        newColorLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

        //[newLayer addSublayer:newColorLayer];
        [self.view.layer addSublayer:newLayer];
        [newLayersArray addObject:newLayer];
    }

    self.layersArray = newLayersArray;
}

-(void) updateLayers {
    double currTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] - self.startTime;

    double currLayerAngle = 0.5 * currTime;

    NSLog(@"%.2f  %.2f", currTime, currLayerAngle);

    //[CATransaction begin];
    //[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
    //[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.0];

    for (CALayer *currLayer in self.layersArray)
    {
        currLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(currLayerAngle, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    //[CATransaction commit];
}

@end
```

Comment: can you please  share some code? what and how are you doing with CALayer?

Comment: Are you testing on real device or simulator? It is better to test performance on the real devices

Comment: Added code to description

Comment: I am testing it on a real device. In activity monitor it shows that some **backboardd** eats much CPU during updates.

Comment: You have to set the duration to 0.0s. All animation properties will have no animation. Otherwise the default time is 0.25 which is not good for performance issue.  If you just use disableActions, in this case , `transform` duration is 0.0 but others, like opacity, hidden etc still have the duration 0.25 seconds. In other words, the CATransaction is not supposed to be completed right away.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it! So it is weak point of core animation, right? It is not so clear from documentation that disabling actions not enough for switching off all animations actually... Anyway, non-zero duration reflects on CPU load? Why not GPU?

Comment: What is best mechanism to disable animations of CALayers properties at all?

Comment: You can set the layer speed to a big number like 10000,00. which make the animation finished as quick as possible.  `self.view.layer.speed = 100000.0`. It's a simple way but may not be the best way.

Comment: Setting duration didn't solved overloaded CPU problem..

Comment: You need to trace down the code why it costs so much load.

Comment: Nothing else left I think=)

Comment: All updates to the model properties are done on the CPU. Once the updates have been processed it is then sent to render server or GPU. So updating the transform updates the model on the CPU. One way to make this more efficient would be to drop the displayLink and use a CAReplicatorLayer or a group of them to get the columns you want. Then apply the animation there although I have not run the example to see the layout you are targeting.

Comment: This code in NOTE_1 is just example, not real goal, so using CAReplicationLayer doesn't match my needs unfortunately. What do you mean by "model update"? What exactly is done behind this? If it is only geometry recalculations, so why does it take so much CPU?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments above, setting `kCATransactionDisableActions` will only affect the current transaction. You might have code in other places that starts implicit animations. Try explicitly setting the layer actions to null. You only need to do this **once**, when the layer is created. In this case you don't need to do explicit transactions.

```
layer.actions = @{ @"contents": [NSNull null], @"position": [NSNull null],
                   @"frame": [NSNull null], @"opacity": [NSNull null],
                   @"bounds": [NSNull null], @"affineTransform": [NSNull null],
                   @"sublayerTransform": [NSNull null], @"transform": [NSNull null],
                   @"zPosition": [NSNull null], @"anchorPoint": [NSNull null],
                   @"cornerRadius": [NSNull null], @"sublayers": [NSNull null],
                   @"onLayout": [NSNull null], };
```

Comment: I tried your advice, but CPU still loaded.. I added my test code as NOTE_1 in description of question. Please, have a look..

Comment: I don't understand why CPU participating in layers updates?? In test code in NOTE_1 I tried to change number of layers: the more layer the more CPU loaded. It seems that each update lead to unloading layers from GPU memory to RAM for processing in CPU. If it not, so what a ....? Moreover, adding empty layer behind colored layer also leads to CPU waste. Why if it is empty and can be considered as just as container? Mystery..